# Why are build and rebuild of my VSIX solution not generting the same output

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions

My project is a Visual Studio Extension. The solution contains multiple projects and references multiple NuGet packages. I am using visual studio 2019 version 16.2.1 and I am using Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools version 16.2.3073.

If I rebuild the complete project, or if I clean the solution before building, everything seems to be built correctly.

However, if I build the solution without cleaning it first, at least one dll is omitted from the VSIX installation. This specific DLL is the output of a second level project reference.

My top level VSIX project is MultiLanguageWPF. This has a project reference to MultiLanguageLegacy, which in turn has a project reference to MultiLangCodeParser. The file MultiLangCodeParser.dll is missing from the VSIX after a build.

```
MultiLanguageWPF
| 
+-- MultiLanguageLegacy
    | 
    +-- MultiLangCodeParser
```

The same problem occurs when I start the debugger using F5, unless I clean the project first (which is particularly annoying).

**How can I prevent this different behavior for build and rebuild?**

*By the way, building my solution always builds the top level project MultiLanguageWPF, even if it has only just been built.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I rebuild the complete project, or if I clean the solution before
>   building, everything seems to be built correctly.

Yes, the solution builds well and it's expected behavior. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#to-build-rebuild-or-clean-an-entire-solution), the rebuild is `clean+build`, so both these two ways work correctly. No matter `rebuild` or `clean and build`, they will build exactly all projects in your solution.In this way, the `MultiLangCodeParser.dll` can be recognized by MultiLanguageWPF and will contain it in vsix package.

> However, if I build the solution without cleaning it first, at least
>   one dll is omitted from the VSIX installation. This specific DLL is
>   the output of a second level project reference.

If I change something in `MultiLanguageWPF` project, now build the solution, since I haven't make any changes to `MultiLanguageLegacy` and `MultiLangCodeParser`, the VS won't actually build these two projects, it will only build the top-level `MultiLanguageWPF` project itself, similar to this:

[image]

When vs only build the top-level project while not rebuilding the first and second level project, the build engine will only read content from MultiLanguageWPF.csproj, in this file it only defines the package reference to `MultiLanguageLegacy`, so it will contain `MultiLanguageLegacy.dll` in .vsix, but won't copy the MultiLangCodeParser.dll cause in this situation the build engine didn't know `MultiLanguageLegacy.dll` depend on `MultiLangCodeParser.dll`. It didn't read data from MultiLanguageLegacy.csproj and build it, **so the engine won't know the dependency relationship between first level and second level projects if it only build the top-level project in my opinion.**

**Workaround:**

I can reproduce the same issue and it do exist, the workaround for your current solution can be adding a script below into `MultiLanguageWPF.csproj`: (Assuming your three projects are in **same solution folder**)

```
  <Target Name="AddCustomItem" AfterTargets="GetVsixSourceItems">
    <ItemGroup>
      <VSIXSourceItem Include="..\MultiLangCodeParser\bin\$(Configuration)\MultiLangCodeParser.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Then this annoying issue seems to go away in my machine.

Comment: Thanks Lance, that works. I feel there might be a better solution, because this seems like a workaround for a bug. Anyway, it works and I can live with it.

Comment: You are right, that's a workaround. It seems similar issue have been reported in github, still open. I will find the link and update it in answer monday!

Comment: @PhilJollans Maybe a similar issue like [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1845), but since I'm not certainly sure, I post a new one by report the problem button in VS. [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/698657/the-second-packagereference-not-always-included-in.html) here.